# How do I read a "string" as multiple chars if I don't know the length of the char sequence?

Tags: c

Sorry if the title is a bit confusing, I'll try to explain better here.
So basically I'm trying to write a program where the user inputs a phone number in an alphabetic form and it then gets translated in a numeric form. Like this:

```
Enter phone number: CALLATT
22555288
```

Where `2=ABC`, `3=DEF`, `4=GHI`, `5=JKL`, `6=MNO`, `7=PRS`, `8=TUV`, `9=WXY`

Also if the phone number input contains chars that are not alphabetical they should be left as they are. Which means:

```
Enter phone number: 1-800-COL-LECT
1-800-265-5328
```

Now, I know that this could be solved very easily using strings and arrays but I'm not supposed to use them for this exercise. I wrote this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  char two = '2', three = '3', four = '4', five = '5', six = '6',
       seven = '7', eight = '8', nine = '9';
  char num;

  printf("Enter a phone number: ");

  do {
    num = getchar();
    if(num == 'A' || num == 'B' || num == 'C'){
      num = two;
    }
    else if(num == 'D' || num == 'E' || num == 'F'){
      num = three;
    }
    else if(num == 'G' || num == 'H' || num == 'I'){
      num = four;
    }
    else if(num == 'J' || num == 'K' || num == 'L'){
      num = five;
    }
    else if(num == 'M' || num == 'N' || num == 'O'){
      num = six;
    }
    else if(num == 'P' || num == 'R' || num == 'S'){
      num = seven;
    }
    else if(num == 'T' || num == 'U' || num == 'V'){
      num = eight;
    }
    else if(num == 'W' || num == 'X' || num == 'Y'){
      num = nine;
    }
    printf("%c", num);
  }while(getchar() != '\n');

  return 0;
}
```

Which doesn't obviously work. I mean, it works just fine if the user inputs a single char but not if the input is composed by more than one char. I can't really get my head around this... I know why and where my code is wrong but I can't really find an effective solution to solve the problem without using arrays.

Any help? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Just a FYI: `char num;` ==> `int num;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
    int num = getchar();
    do {

        /* your if / else / if train */
        printf("%c", num);

    } while ((num = getchar()) != '\n'); // assign and compare
```

Comment: Thanks that helped. So basically as I wrote it it was listening for 2 chars at once instead of 1, right?

Comment: Basically you were wasting 1 char for every two chars typed.